# linux - screen command - how to kill a screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I'm using screen on my home server.  I start it by issuing

```
screen -dmS [name]
```

Then, when I've connected I can Ctrl+A, n to jump between screens and Ctrl+A, c to create new ones... How, however, I have too many and I'd like to remove one of them.  How do I do that?  How do I go from Ctrl+A, n 4 times down to Ctrl+A, n 3 times to cycle through all of them?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: This is in `man` page territory. Or a simple search for "Linux screen tutorial".

Comment: I'm sure this is true, but screen, like many linux utilities has, like, 100 functions when I really only use 5 of them.  It was not at all obvious to me when I poured through all of that documentation....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>n</kbd> will take you to the next window, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>p</kbd> to the previous one. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>..<kbd>9</kbd> will allow you to switch to a particular screen.

"exit" is to kill screen session.

Comment: <lightbulb>  Ah!  I now understand more what screen is!  That makes so much sense!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simply exit one of the shells you started with "Ctrl+A c". Usually a Ctrl-D or `exit` is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't terminate the program ran in a screen window(e.g. terminate shells by using `exit`), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>,<kbd>k</kbd> will allow you to kill the window, after prompting you for a confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Just exit the shell that is running in that screen and the window will close.